# Android studio says VT-x is disabled while it's enabled

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to run a simple project in android studio but I get the error saying :
"VT-x is disabled in BIOS. Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)." While being pretty clear what the problem is, it's just wrong since I've checked (multiple times) that it is indeed enabled in my bios (Gigabyte by the way). I have the same error message when I try to install Intel HAXM :
"Unable to install Intel® HAXM
VT-x is disabled in BIOS.
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)."
I don't really care about HAXM,it was just to see if the error message was the same or not.

To be sure that it is indeed enabled, I downloaded this piece of software (Intel Processor Identification Utility-Legacy) that gives information about my CPU. [image: CPU specs that are activated]
It is in French but it clearly says VT-x is enabled.

The weirdest thing is that I used to run android studio without any kind of problem years ago but today, I can't seem to make it work. I've read somewhere that Hyper-V could be a cause so I disabled it on my pc too. Also the funny thing is that I have no problem using virtual box. I uninstalled it a few hours ago to see if there were any interference but to no avail.
I've also disabled the setting in Avast "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization".

I'm kinda lost to what I could/should do, so if anybody has a guess, I would be extremely grateful

Comment: I don't know French but in the above image. It is saying that your Intel Processor is supporting VT-X not saying that VT-X is enabled in your BIOS. By default, VT-X is disabled in old PC. I think you have to check once in BIOS that Virtualization is enabled or not.

Comment: I checked multiple times in the bios that VT-x is actually enabled with no success so far. I gave up and went with genymotion which seems to work. It's a workaround I suppose